# How do I change my health app from a bar graph to a line graph?

Tags: ios, health.app

I was using the Health App under iOS 9.2 - and in the 9.3 upgrade the Health App switched display from a line graph to a bar graph.

I like the line graph better. I can't figure out how to get it back.

My question is: **How do I change my health app from a bar graph to a line graph?**

Comment: I have tried everything and it only allows me to edit the data. I would to know the answer as well. The line graph is a better tool to track trends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply the answer is: you can not change because of the update